Apache reload - closing connections never close, old gen slots don't die off, scoreboard fills up
We are running Rocky 9.4 with httpd 2.4.57-11 in MPM-Event, php(-fpm) 8.2
Usually, for our live webservers, when we change any config, we reload apache so there's no gap in service at all. Apache usually generates new slots/servers to handle any new requests, and marks the current slots/servers as old gen, stopping new requests and tries to close the connections down. Then, when the requests to the old slots are fulfilled, they die off.
With one particular server however, it seems to have trouble closing 1 or 2 connections, and then none of the old gen slots die off. Successive reloads then gradually fill up the scoreboard with old gen slots that don't accept any new connections and eventually hits the ServerLimit and we get the 'Scoreboard Full' error message and the server stops serving out pages as there's no active slots.
One other thing to note is that when performing a graceful restart it would stop serving for 90s or so, before finally restarting and serving pages again.
In the short term we've increased the ServerLimit to cope a bit longer between restarts (Apache or Server). We've also lowered the GracefulShutdownTimeout to 10, which helps during a restart to limit the outage for a very short periodn, but we still get complaints from live website users. However, these are merely masking the issue.
I've done a fair amount of searching to see if I could find a similar issue, and couldn't really find anything that wasn't already solved by a version update or had slightly different scoreboard output (like they were still accepting or had G's in the scoreboard)
I had found that some people had issues with wsgi/python scripts, but when I look at the urls being requested on the slot with stuck closing connections, they're not accessing the vhost that is running a wsgi module so I don't really know where to go next.
I think, what I need to do next is figure out what the connections are that are not closing, and why they aren't closing, and then figure out how to close them, so that's really the question I am asking (unless you know instantly what this could be)
How can I go about troubleshooting this issue, to figure out what's up with the connections that won't close, and how to go about fixing that
Example Scoreboard:
Server Version: Apache/2.4.57 (Rocky Linux) OpenSSL/3.0.7 mod_auth_gssapi/1.6.3 SVN/1.14.1 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9
Server MPM: event
Server Built: Jul 4 2024 00:00:00
Current Time: Tuesday, 30-Jul-2024 14:00:03 BST
Restart Time: Tuesday, 30-Jul-2024 12:48:53 BST
Parent Server Config. Generation: 2
Parent Server MPM Generation: 1
Server uptime: 1 hour 11 minutes 10 seconds
Server load: 0.03 0.02 0.00
Total accesses: 3557 - Total Traffic: 35.9 MB - Total Duration: 58869
CPU Usage: u.25 s.21 cu0 cs0 - .0108% CPU load
.833 requests/sec - 8.6 kB/second - 10.3 kB/request - 16.5502 ms/request
1 requests currently being processed, 0 workers gracefully restarting, 74 idle workers


................................................................
....................................____________________________
________________________________W______________.................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................
Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Srv Connections from the closing slots:
Srv PID Acc M   CPU SS  Req Dur Conn    Child   Slot    Client  Protocol    VHost   Request
0-0 -   0/0/25  .   0.00    1154    0   747 0.0 0.00    0.22    10.1.0.142  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/28  .   0.00    1154    85  328 0.0 0.00    0.56    10.1.1.239  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/30  .   0.00    1154    0   541 0.0 0.00    0.28    10.1.1.74   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/23  .   0.00    1154    0   87  0.0 0.00    0.18    10.1.0.190  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/21  .   0.00    1154    0   767 0.0 0.00    0.38    10.1.0.3    http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/35  .   0.00    1154    0   753 0.0 0.00    0.36    10.1.1.57   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/26  .   0.00    1154    0   529 0.0 0.00    0.24    10.1.1.231  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/31  .   0.00    1154    91  319 0.0 0.00    0.41    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/28  .   0.00    1154    39  1342    0.0 0.00    0.29    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php/help/tips/tickets.queue HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/25  .   0.00    1154    0   426 0.0 0.00    0.33    10.1.0.93   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/32  .   0.00    1154    0   86  0.0 0.00    0.32    10.1.0.109  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/23  .   0.00    1154    36  881 0.0 0.00    0.17    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /scp/ajax.php/queue/counts HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/33  .   0.00    1154    0   100 0.0 0.00    0.44    10.1.1.76   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/25  .   0.00    1152    25  835 0.0 0.00    0.31    10.1.1.229  http/1.1    wsgi.domain.name:443    GET /projects/chrome/common/trac_logo_mini.png HTTP/
0-0 -   0/0/22  .   0.00    1154    0   170 0.0 0.00    0.24    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/27  .   0.00    1154    0   170 0.0 0.00    0.28    10.1.1.76   http/1.1        
0-0 -   0/0/24  .   0.00    1154    0   819 0.0 0.00    0.23    10.1.0.91   http/1.1        
0-0 -   0/0/28  .   0.00    1154    0   938 0.0 0.00    0.22    10.1.0.109  http/1.1        
0-0 -   0/0/25  .   0.00    1154    0   552 0.0 0.00    0.20    10.1.0.91   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/32  .   0.00    1154    0   171 0.0 0.00    0.29    10.1.1.33   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    0   65  0.0 0.00    0.14    10.1.0.219  http/1.1        
0-0 -   0/0/32  .   0.00    1154    0   103 0.0 0.00    0.31    10.1.0.224  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
0-0 -   0/0/30  .   0.00    1154    0   515 0.0 0.00    0.24    10.1.0.219  http/1.1        
0-0 -   0/0/31  .   0.00    1154    0   248 0.0 0.00    0.24    10.1.1.33   http/1.1        
0-0 -   0/0/31  .   0.00    1154    0   323 0.0 0.00    0.43    10.1.0.190  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/21  .   0.00    1154    90  1076    0.0 0.00    0.20    10.2.10.113 http/1.1        
1-0 -   0/0/13  .   0.00    1154    0   2   0.0 0.00    0.10    10.1.0.197  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/22  .   0.00    1154    0   50  0.0 0.00    0.21    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /gravel/index_s.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/15  .   0.00    1154    0   380 0.0 0.00    0.11    10.1.0.83   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/16  .   0.00    1154    0   151 0.0 0.00    0.23    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /templates/assets/logo
1-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    0   419 0.0 0.00    0.36    10.1.0.133  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/19  .   0.00    1154    0   296 0.0 0.00    0.26    10.1.0.64   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    37  478 0.0 0.00    0.13    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /scp/ajax.php/queue/counts HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    0   250 0.0 0.00    0.18    192.168.221.14  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/22  .   0.00    1154    0   131 0.0 0.00    0.33    10.1.1.40   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    0   522 0.0 0.00    0.46    10.1.0.111  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    0   491 0.0 0.00    0.18    10.1.0.91   http/1.1        
1-0 -   0/0/17  .   0.00    1154    39  40  0.0 0.00    0.07    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /scp/ajax.php/queue/counts HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/23  .   0.00    1154    0   43  0.0 0.00    0.18    10.1.1.241  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/22  .   0.00    1154    0   29  0.0 0.00    0.10    10.1.0.91   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/21  .   0.00    1154    0   500 0.0 0.00    0.77    10.1.0.109  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/22  .   0.00    1154    0   334 0.0 0.00    0.22    10.1.0.111  http/1.1        
1-0 -   0/0/23  .   0.00    1154    0   46  0.0 0.00    0.20    10.1.0.91   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/20  .   0.00    1154    0   5   0.0 0.00    0.15    10.1.0.109  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/21  .   0.00    1154    0   22  0.0 0.00    0.23    10.1.0.229  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/22  .   0.00    1154    130 624 0.0 0.00    0.28    10.1.1.229  http/1.1    second.domain.name:443  GET /index.php?title=Ice_Cream HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/16  .   0.00    1154    0   20  0.0 0.00    0.11    10.1.0.133  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/23  .   0.00    1154    92  291 0.0 0.00    0.31    10.1.0.217  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/18  .   0.00    1154    379 1086    0.0 0.00    0.31    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
1-0 -   0/0/14  .   0.00    1154    0   412 0.0 0.00    0.14    10.2.10.113 http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/50  .   0.00    1154    0   147 0.0 0.00    0.35    10.1.0.126  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/41  .   0.00    1154    0   84  0.0 0.00    0.27    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /digital-gallery/pictures/IceCream/ H
2-0 -   0/0/43  .   0.00    1154    0   928 0.0 0.00    0.55    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/44  .   0.00    1154    0   706 0.0 0.00    0.35    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/42  .   0.00    1154    0   251 0.0 0.00    0.30    10.1.0.91   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/45  .   0.00    1154    70  818 0.0 0.00    0.51    10.1.1.239  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/40  .   0.00    1154    0   1245    0.0 0.00    0.26    10.1.0.213  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/37  .   0.00    1154    0   580 0.0 0.00    0.29    10.1.1.231  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/41  .   0.00    1154    69  250 0.0 0.00    0.31    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/37  .   0.00    1154    0   63  0.0 0.00    0.26    10.1.1.35   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/28  .   0.00    1154    0   63  0.0 0.00    0.19    10.1.1.235  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/42  .   0.00    1154    37  351 0.0 0.00    0.39    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /scp/ajax.php/queue/counts HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/45  .   0.00    1154    0   195 0.0 0.00    0.37    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET / HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/43  .   0.00    1154    0   295 0.0 0.00    0.51    10.1.0.194  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/34  .   0.00    1154    0   102 0.0 0.00    0.27    10.1.0.157  http/1.1        
2-0 -   0/0/36  .   0.00    1152    0   774 0.0 0.00    0.34    10.1.0.190  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/32  .   0.00    1154    187 394 0.0 0.00    0.29    10.1.1.229  http/1.1    wsgi.domain.name:443    GET /projects/ HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/31  .   0.00    1152    0   357 0.0 0.00    0.28    10.1.0.190  http/1.1        
2-0 -   0/0/38  .   0.00    1154    21  126 0.0 0.00    0.38    10.1.1.229  http/1.1    wsgi.domain.name:443    GET /projects/chrome/common/extlink.gif HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/33  .   0.00    1154    0   129 0.0 0.00    0.25    10.1.1.72   http/1.1        
2-0 -   0/0/35  .   0.00    1154    337 1476    0.0 0.00    0.39    10.1.1.225  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1&_pjax=%23pjax-container HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/38  .   0.00    1154    0   1486    0.0 0.00    0.41    10.1.0.213  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/36  .   0.00    1154    0   138 0.0 0.00    0.19    10.1.1.76   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/36  .   0.00    1154    0   202 0.0 0.00    0.28    10.1.0.250  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
2-0 -   0/0/48  .   0.00    1154    0   1127    0.0 0.00    0.57    10.1.1.236  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/59  .   0.00    1154    0   711 0.0 0.00    0.55    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /templates/assets/img/footer_logos/
3-0 -   0/0/45  .   0.00    1152    0   1194    0.0 0.00    0.50    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /templates/assets/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/56  .   0.00    1154    0   870 0.0 0.00    0.49    10.1.1.241  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/53  .   0.00    1152    0   1080    0.0 0.00    0.65    10.1.1.76   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/53  .   0.00    1154    0   641 0.0 0.00    0.48    10.1.0.126  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/56  .   0.00    1154    0   1565    0.0 0.00    0.46    10.1.1.244  http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /scp/images/icons/ticket_source_phone.gif HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/57  .   0.00    1154    350 1763    0.0 0.00    0.65    10.1.1.72   http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /dru/list.php?queue=1 HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/54  .   0.00    1152    0   1138    0.0 0.00    0.70    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/62  .   0.00    1152    0   1447    0.0 0.00    0.59    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/55  .   0.00    1154    0   274 0.0 0.00    0.60    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/56  .   0.00    1154    0   544 0.0 0.00    0.42    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/55  .   0.00    1154    0   382 0.0 0.00    0.62    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/63  .   0.00    1154    35  1378    0.0 0.00    0.76    10.1.1.72   http/1.1    alt.sub.domain.name:443 GET /scp/autocron.php HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/58  .   0.00    1154    0   1156    0.0 0.00    0.51    10.1.0.91   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/48  .   0.00    1152    0   484 0.0 0.00    0.48    192.168.221.14  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/62  .   0.00    1152    0   956 0.0 0.00    0.58    10.1.0.224  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/47  .   0.00    1154    0   1398    0.0 0.00    0.45    192.168.221.14  http/1.1        
3-0 -   0/0/51  .   0.00    1154    0   458 0.0 0.00    0.31    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/60  .   0.00    1152    0   2056    0.0 0.00    1.11    10.20.10.21 http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /templates/assets/logo
3-0 -   0/0/49  .   0.00    1154    0   2646    0.0 0.00    0.56    10.1.0.250  http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/62  .   0.00    1152    0   1022    0.0 0.00    0.56    10.1.1.76   http/1.1    www.domain.name:443 GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/55  .   0.00    1154    0   1056    0.0 0.00    0.43    192.168.221.14  http/1.1        
3-0 -   0/0/50  .   0.00    1154    0   727 0.0 0.00    0.47    192.168.221.14  http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1
3-0 -   0/0/51  .   0.00    1154    365 1564    0.0 0.00    0.44    10.1.1.76   http/1.1        
3-0 -   0/0/62  .   0.00    1152    0   422 0.0 0.00    0.70    10.1.0.32   http/1.1    www.domain.name:80  GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1


tldr; what steps should I take, or tools should I use, to try and figure out why the connections aren't closing
